# An identity involving the Dirichlet integral

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

For $v: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow [0,1]$ a Lipschitz continuous function, define $I(v,B) = \int_{B} || \nabla v||^2 d \lambda = \int \int _{B} [(\partial_{x} v)^2 + (\partial_{y} v)^2] dxdy$ where $d \lambda$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $B \subset \mathbb{C}$ is Borel.

It is apparently an identity that for $v_1,v_2 : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow [0,1]$ Lipschitz continuous, that $I(v_1,\mathbb{C}) + I(v_2, \mathbb{C}) = I(\text{min}(v_1,v_2) , \mathbb{C}) + I(\text{max}(v_1,v_2) , \mathbb{C})$ but I cannot see why.

(Note that $\text{max}(v_1,v_2)$ and $\min(v_1,v_2)$ are Lipschitz since $v_1,v_2$ are.)

The most I have been able to reason through this problem is that this would hold if for example, we could show that $(v_1 - v_2)^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ had measure zero. But I'm pretty sure this is false, so there must be another approach I am missing towards establishing this identity.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is because $\nabla \min(v_1,v_2)= \nabla v_1$ a.e. on the set $\{ v_1\leq v_2\}$, and a similar symmetric statement. You can find statements like these on books dealing with Sobolev spaces (for example I think Evans' PDE book has it)

Comment: @Jose27 thank you for your comment, I'll take a look at evans PDE

Comment: @Jose27 I found it in Evans and Gariepy , and as you say it actually holds for $v_1,v_2 \in W^{1,p}$

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the @Jose27's comment. That is, the result stated in the comment is contained in page 130 Theorem 4 (iii) of Evans and Gariepy "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions", with a full (pretty much self-contained) proof on page 131.